# ¿Por qué reacciona así está función generadora en JS?

Tags: javascript, funciones

He estado investigando acerca de las funciones generadoras en JavaScript y no consigo aclarar que significa el `done: true/false` que generan yield/return.

Tampoco saco en claro por que el último `yield` devuelve `undefined` siendo que es una cadena de texto como `"Y";`

¿Alguien podría aclararlo?

Adjunto el código en cuestión:

```js
function* yieldAndReturn() {
  yield "Y";
  return "R";
  yield "unreachable";
}

var gen = yieldAndReturn()
console.log(gen.next()); // { value: "Y", done: false }
console.log(gen.next()); // { value: "R", done: true }
console.log(gen.next()); // { value: undefined, done: true }
```

Comment: El último yield está después del return...

Comment: Y eso significa que..?¿

Comment: Que nunca se llega a esa parte del código, la función acaba antes. De hecho, un lenguaje de programación "serio" ]:) avisaría de que esa instrucción es inaccesible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Qué significa el done: true/false que generan `yield/return.`

Estos valores representan el fin o no de la función generadora. retorna `false` cuando aún hay valores  y `true` cuando no los hay **o** llega la palabra reservada `return` *(como su caso)* , está palabra clave es la que da fin al generador.

Después de un `return` ya no tiene sentido tener más `yield`, porque
[habrá finalizado la función como dice la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/yield), donde la parte más importante para su ejemplo es.

> Sí alcanza el final de la función del generador; en este caso, la
>   ejecución del generador termina y IteratorResultse, el valor de  `value` es `undefined` y `done` es `true`.

**Ejm**

```js
function* yieldAndReturn() {
  yield "Y1";
  return "R"; 
  yield "unreachable"; // valor indefinido , done : true
}
function* yieldAndReturn2() {
  yield "Y1";
  yield "unreachable";
  return "R"; 
  
}

var gen = yieldAndReturn()
var gen2 = yieldAndReturn2()
console.log(gen.next()); // { value: "Y", done: false }
console.log(gen.next()); // { value: "R", done: true }
console.log(gen.next()); // { value: undefined, done: true }


console.log(gen2.next()); // { value: "Y", done: false }
console.log(gen2.next()); // { value: "unreachable", done: false }
console.log(gen2.next()); // { value: R, done: true }
```